# Dummit's Abstract Algebra book, Exercise 9, Sec.3.2.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$ G $ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime dividing $|G|$,
$
S=\left \{ \left ( {x}_{1},{x}_{2},...,{x}_{p} \right ) | x_{i}\in G\space and\space x_{1}x_{2}...x_{p} = 1 \right \}
$
.
Show that $S$ has $|G|^{p-1}$ elements.

This problem is the first step of proving Cauchy's Theorem in Abstract Algebra.
The complete proof is due to James McKay which was published on *Amer.Math.Monthly, 66(1959),p119*.

I have tried to construct an epimorphism from $G^{(p)}$ onto $G$ sending $(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{p})$ to $x_{1}x_{2}...x_{p}$, but I don't know how to define a multiplication fitting the condition $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)$.
If we let $A_{g_{i}} = \left \{ \left ( {x}_{1},{x}_{2},...,{x}_{p} \right ) | x_{i}\in G\space and\space x_{1}x_{2}...x_{p} = g_{i} \right \}$, then it's clear that the set of $A_{g_{i}}$ is a group by defining $A_{g_{i}} \cdot A_{g_{j}} = A_{g_{i}\cdot g_{j}}$ . But this is still helpless.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\;S\subset G^p:=\overbrace{G\times\ldots\times G}^{p\;\text{times}}\;$ is not a subgroup of the cartesian product (=direct product, in this case) $\;G^p\;$, and I can't understand what do you want some homomorphism from $\;G^{(p)}:=\langle x^p\;|\;x\in G\rangle\;$ to $\;G\;$ for at all... If your problem is to prove that $\;|S|=|G|^{p-1}\;$ then you can argue as follows:

An element $\;(x_1,...,x_p)\in G^p\;$ belongs to $\;S\;$ iff

$$x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_p=1\iff x_p=(x_1\cdot\ldots\cdot x_{p-1})^{-1}$$

and thus we can see that an element in $\;S\;$ is uniquely and completely determined by its first $\;p-1\;$ coordinates, and thus $\;|S|=|G|^{p-1}\;$ ...as easy as that.